# Checking condition from two columns and accordingly populate values from 3rd column in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

Following table is given:-

| person | date | sales |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 10/02/2020 | 10 |
| A | 11/02/2020 | 20 |
| A | 12/02/2020 | 30 |
| B | 13/02/2020 | 40 |
| C | 14/02/2020 | 50 |

on given dates we need to check sales corresponding each person as shown in the following table.

**reqd output:-**

| date | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10/02/2020 | 10 |  |  |
| 11/02/2020 | 20 |  |  |
| 12/02/2020 | 30 |  |  |
| 13/02/2020 |  | 40 |  |
| 14/02/2020 |  |  | 50 |

I was able to get this output using pivot table but need to articulate the same output using formulas of excel.

I got this logic that excel would match the date and person an fetch the corresponding sales. But unable to implement this logic to find.**There are more than 10000 rows so can't use if else straight away**
Need some logic which can be populated in all the rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using `Excel2010` then give a try below formula-

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($C$2:$C$6,MATCH(G$1&$F2,$A$2:$A$6&$B$2:$B$6,0)),"")
```

[image]

Comment: You may need to enter the formulas as array means pressing `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER` if it do not work in normal mode.

Answer (score -1):

Using a pivot table was the right way to solve this problem, why exactly do you need to change that ?

Doing it using formulas will, if possible at all, likely be extremely unstable and depend on things such as the sorted order of the records.